# Shorten Ruby code with defined?

Tags: ruby

Is there a shorter way of writing next code in Ruby:

```
if defined?($servlet_context) then true
else false
end
```

Comment: It's exactly the same as **defined?($servlet_context)**. Do you want to do more in the if-else block?

Comment: @iltempo: No, it is not exactly the same, the `defined?` operator does not give you a boolean value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`defined?` operator evaluates to a string or `nil`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html#UG):

> The `defined?` operator returns `nil` if its argument (which can be an arbitrary expression) is not defined, otherwise it returns a description of that argument.

So if you just want something truthy then `defined?($servlet_context)` will do. However, if you absolutely must have a boolean value, then you can use a double-bang cast:

```
!!defined?($servlet_context)
```

Answer (score 0):

`defined?($servlet_context)` will have the exact same effect.

Also then is not required in ruby so the easiest way to shorten it is  - remove 'then'.

Comment: Not the exact same effect, *nearly* the same effect.